# How to properly align "AddThis" social buttons with CSS

Tags: html, css, addthis

I am trying to align the social media buttons seen at the top of [dirtycookie.co](http://dirtycookie.co)

They are aligned properly but there is a bunch of spacing between them.

My HTML:

```
<div class="grid_12 socialheader">
<!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style" style="text-align:center;">
<a class="addthis_button_facebook_like" fb:like:layout="button_count" addthis:url="http://www.facebook.com/TheDirtyCookie"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_tweet"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_pinterest_pinit" pi:pinit:url="http://www.dirtycookie.co" pi:pinit:media="http://distilleryimage6.s3.amazonaws.com/1bf5b1a46d0b11e2914122000a9f1439_6.jpg" pi:pinit:layout="horizontal" always-show-count="1"></a> 
<a class="addthis_button_google_plusone" g:plusone:size="medium"></a> 
<a class="addthis_counter addthis_pill_style"></a>
</div>
<!-- AddThis Button END -->
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
.socialheader {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 3px 1px 0px 1px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.socialheader a{
    padding: 0px 10px 0px 20px !important;
    margin: 0px !important;
    width: 50px !important;
    display:inline !important;
    text-align: center;
    float: center !important;
    position:relative !important;
    top:0px !important;
}
```

I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong :/

Ideally, these widgets would be snug together and centered in the middle of the page. It's also worth noting that the pinterest button should have a counter to the right of it, but doesn't. If anyone knows why that is happening, let me know.

Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: The problem seems to be that the widget iframes are wider than they need to be. You won't be able to override that with local CSS. I'm not sure what's happening, though. I've used AddThis before and not seen this problem. UPDATE: I suspect it's because you're using the counters on your widget buttons. They require some extra space for growth.

Comment: Glad to see I'm not the only one :)

Answer (score 4):

You're using the counters on your widget buttons. They require some extra space for growth, and as they're served as iframes you cannot modify their styles.

I suggest that you show plain buttons without counters or stack the widgets vertically so that the extra space on the right isn't a design problem.

UPDATE: The widgets aren't centering for you because the widget styles float them left. You can do this to override:

```
.socialheader a {
    float: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @isherwood. There are plenty of sites that use the counters and the buttons adapt to the growth, allowing the "social bar" to stay snug with an even 2px padding between them. Also, that still doesn't explain why the buttons aren't centered.

Comment: I've updated my answer with information about your centering problem.

Comment: I've updated my question with the added CSS. It did center the elements, now the alignment is screwy... and one got pushed below... I'm looking for an example now as well.

Comment: Thanks for your help on this btw :)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with getting the icons to center align. I added the following CSS class and it worked for me:

```
div.addthis_toolbox.addthis_default_style {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

For older browsers, you can also try:

```
div.addthis_toolbox.addthis_default_style {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 180px;
}
```